# Can I check the quality of my Graphics Card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have an old Laptop that is running into some performance issues. It's mainly used for Document Control, so it isn't built to be Process-heavy. However, lately it has been having more and more issues crashing due to high memory usage. (Upwards of 2 Gb).

Specs:

- Toshiba Satellite C850
- Windows 7 Professional
- Intel Core i5-2450M CPU @2.50 GHz
- 4 Gb RAM
- 64-bit OS.

I believe the issue of the crashes is mainly due to the high memory usage, as the main programs that are used are Adobe Reader and Photoshop, with the possibility of Java kicking in occasionally to run web apps. A lot of PDF checking going on. Along with the small RAM capacity, it seems like a valid reason.

However, being an old machine, is it possible that graphics card could cause issues as well? How can I check it's integrity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard tools among overclockers for testing components for hardware issues are:

1. [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for testing RAM.  It writes patterns to the memory and reads them back to see if they got written properly, while doing very little work with the CPU.
2. [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/download/) in CPU stress-test mode.  It performs complex mathematical operations to stress the CPU while not using much RAM.
3. [3DMark](http://www.3dmark.com/) in looping benchmark mode.  This is designed to stress-test your GPU, but unlike the other tests, it also puts a significant load on RAM and the CPU.  In general, if you see failures with 3DMark but not with Memtest86+ or Prime95, it's a graphics card problem.